# How do I get GOOGLEFINANCE to return only the date and not the date and time of stock price history?

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("NASDAQ:GOOGL","close",date(2021,1,1),today(),1)
```

returns closing history in two columns "Date" and "Close" since Jan. 1, 2021. The date column displays date and time values:

```
1/4/2021 16:00:00
1/5/2021 16:00:00
1/6/2021 16:00:00
1/7/2021 16:00:00
```

How do I modify the formula to return only the date and not the time?

```
1/4/2021
1/5/2021
1/6/2021
1/7/2021
```

Comment: Have you tried formatting the "Date" column as "Date"?

Answer (score -1):

Here you go:

```
=QUERY(GOOGLEFINANCE("NASDAQ:GOOGL","close",date(2021,1,1),today(),1),"select Col1"
)
```

Then you go to to 123, which is below the the tools menu and check date. That's it.